# Texto e imagem responsiva

Tags: html, css

sou meio novato trabalhando com métodos responsivos e estou tendo problemas com um detalhe, preciso trocar o texto de um btn por uma imagem quando minha aplicação for acessada por celular.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isso?

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block text-uppercase" id="prosseguir" type="submit">Prosseguir</button>
```

Eu gostaria que ao redimensionar a tela, o btn substituísse o "Prosseguir" por um icone.

Grato.

Comment: Aparentemente você está usando Bootstrap. Essa informação é correta? Se sim, qual versão?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como complemento à resposta do Hugo, o Bootstrap já tem ferramentas para alterar a propriedade `display` variando de acordo com a largura do viewport (através das [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)). São as classes `d-*` ([documentação](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/utilities/display/)).

***OBS**: quando me referir à `xs`, é o [tamanho da tela](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#par%C3%A2metros-grid) (< 576px). Pois o [BT4 usa a abordagem Mobile First](https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#breakpoints-reponsivos), ou seja, se não especificado explicitamente os estilos são aplicados à telas `xs` (extra small)*

Você pode dizer para imagem ficar escondida em todas as larguras, exceto `xs` usando as classes:

```
<span class="d-none d-sm-block">Prosseguir</span>
```

`d-none` faz com que o `span` seja `display: none`, e `d-sm-block` faz com que seja `display: block` para telas `sm` ou maiores, ou seja, ficará oculto apenas em telas `xs`.

Já na imagem você usaria:

```
<img class="d-inline-block d-sm-none" src="...">
```

`d-inline-block` faz com que a `img` seja `display: inline-block`, e `d-sm-none` faz com que seja `display: none` para telas `sm` ou maiores, ou seja, ficará visível apenas em telas `xs`.

Dessa maneira a visibilidade do `span` e do `img` ficam mutuamente excludentes.

Exemplo:

```css
html, body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<main class="container">
  <div class="row">
  
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block text-uppercase">
      <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Prosseguir</span>
      
      <img class="d-inline-block d-sm-none" src="https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" style="max-width: 50px;">
      
    </button>
    
  </div>
</main>
```

*Você pode deixar o snippet em tela cheia (link "página toda") e alterar a largura da janela do seu navegador para ver a responsividade funcionando*

Comment: Bootstrap 4 não tem XS ;) https://getbootstrap.com.br/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#par%C3%A2metros-grid Outra dica, já que não vai ter texto no button, não se esqueça de colocar ALT na imagem

Comment: Eu reli a resposta e não vi onde disse classes XS. Eu disse tamanho de tela XS. E não tem a classe XS porque ela é a padrão (Extra small < 576px) devido à abordagem Mobile-First. Me ajuda aí Hugo, não entendi o porquê do comentário. hahahah

Comment: É pq no Bootstrap 3 existe col-xs-* e XS é usado em várias outras coisas, já no Bootstrap 4 XS deixou de existir... as vezes isso pode confundir as pessoas. Foi apenas uma observação

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certinho as dicas de vocês e obrigado pelos links de documentação, me elucidou bastante.

Answer (score 3):

Existem vária formas de fazer e uma delas é colocando um `span` dentro do `button` como eu fiz nesse exemplo. depois com a regra `@media` vc esconde e mostra esse `span`, ao mesmo tempo que vc retira o texto do `bottun` colocando o `font-size:0` por exemplo.

Então caso a tela tenha no máximo `610px` de largura a imagem aparece, caso seja mais quer `610px` o texto do `button` aparece. Vc pode ajustar isso na regra `@media` caso queira

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A início vc pode pensar que não é uma forma totalmente semântica, porém o lado positivo é que mesmo com o `font-size:0` o texto pode continuar visível para leitores de tela, porém não aparece para o usuário comum.

Veja o código correspondente a imagem acima:

```css
.icon {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/16/16);
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:610px) {
    .icon {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    button {
        font-size: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block text-uppercase" id="prosseguir" type="submit">
    Prosseguir
    <span class="icon"></span>
</button>
```